# Ok to Monkey Patch Object class to create custom data formatters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app has various data formatting rules such as if value == "-" then display "N/A" or if value == "NULL" then display "N/A" or if value.is_a? Numeric then value.round(2) and various other such rules. I currently have a helper method that does it as follows

```
def display_formatted
 case
  when '.'
    #...
 end
end
```

Is it ok to MonkeyPatch the Object class to create a formatter like

```
class Object
  def my_app_format
    case self
      when is_a?(Numeric)
       # some rules
      when "-"
       # some other rule
      else
        self
  end
end
```

Currently the code is littered with display_formatted(value) in hundreds of places and I want to add different formatters so I can use it as follows and on any data type and in plain Ruby not Rails!

```
value.as_count_formatted
value.as_default_formatted
value.as_default_rounded`
```

Reason for patching it on the Object class is that the data type is not always known as the source data is not schematic so a field can have numeric or string values.

Comment: Sounds like you're merely replacing `foo_bar(obj)` with `obj.foo_bar`.

Comment: @Stefan yes and no. `obj.foo_bar` sort of reads better but another reason is that I need to do it in so many places that having something native by the way of monkey patching makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  But mostly no.

As stefan mentions in the comment, "you're merely replacing foo_bar(obj) with obj.foo_bar".  I agree that this assessment seems to generally sum up your changes.

This change would be "okay" in the sense that there are no obvious reasons for it to problematically change program behavior.

But there is a problem that monkey patching is generally frowned up and regarded as hacky.  A big reason for this is that monkey patching can be done anywhere and it can be difficult to track down if you are not the person who wrote it.  Even worse, it can also be the source of subtle and hard to track down bugs if replacing an existing function (although that is not the case here).

Ruby gives almost unlimited flexibility to programmers, but care must be taken with that flexibility.

On a purely technical level (will it work and keep correct functionality?) the answer is yes.  On a more opinionated level (is this considered good practice?) I would say no - and that would be my advice (don't do it).  In general, best practice is to avoid monkey patching unless there is a very good reason for it.